# Is it possible to set up a BroadcastReceiver that listens for ANRs?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-anr-dialog

Within the [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) documentation, one can find the constant `Intent.ACTION_APP_ERROR`which is broadcasted when:

> The user pressed the "Report" button in the crash/ANR dialog.

Is it possible to set up a BroadcastReceiver that listens for an intent broadcasted right after the System sets up the ANR dialog, so that the user input is not involved? If not, is there an alternative method that could trigger some action after detecting that event?

Comment: Are you looking for something to detect when your own app has crashed?

Comment: No, I am already logging crashes internally. I am looking for a way to log [Application Not Responding](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html) instances. For example, if my app does not respond to user input for a period of time, an ANR dialogue will be shown to the user. I want to be able to identify that event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking whether you can catch the event from the system, the answer as far as I know is no.

If you are asking for a way to detect it, see [here](https://github.com/SalomonBrys/ANR-WatchDog).

Comment: Thanks for the WatchDog suggestion. I will try it and see how it works. I hope that the watchdog thread does not use too many resources.

Comment: Eliezer thanks again for the suggestion! I've been using the WatchDog for the past weeks and it has helped me improve my code dramatically! Good call.